# shape operator of a polynomial

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Given a bivariate polynomial of sufficient degree $P(x,y)$, I want to
calculate the principal curvature direction at every point $(x,y)$ for
the surface $(x,y, P(x,y))$. So to do that i need to calculate the
eigenvectors of the shape operator at point $(x,y)$, or so i think. So
to conclude what i think i have to do:

Surface parameterised by $S(u,v) = (u,v,P(u,v))$

Coefficients of First fundamental form:

$$E = 1+f_u^2$$ $$F = f_u*f_v$$ $$G = 1+f_v^2$$

Coefficients of Second fundamental form:

$$L=\frac{f_{uu}}{\sqrt{1+f_u^2+f_v^2}}$$
$$M=\frac{f_{uv}}{\sqrt{1+f_u^2+f_v^2}}$$
$$N=\frac{f_{vv}}{\sqrt{1+f_u^2+f_v^2}}$$

with $f_u = P_x = \frac{\delta f(x,y)}{\delta x}$, $f_v = P_y = \frac{\delta P(x,y)}{\delta y}$, $f_{uu} = P_{xx} = \frac{\delta^2 f(x)}{\delta^2 x}$ and so on.

shape operator from weingarten equations:

$$-S = \begin{matrix} \frac{FM-GL}{EG-F^2} & \frac{FL-EM}{EG-F^2}\\ \frac{FN-GM}{EG-F^2} & \frac{FM-EN}{EG-F^2}  \end{matrix}$$

eigenvectors of the shape operator for (u,v)=(x,y) are the principal
curvature directions in tangent space at point (x,y)

My problem is that i now get complex eigen vectors which i cant rly
interpret in this context, so where did i go wrong? The Weingarten
equations are in regards to a basis, which was one thing i didnt quite
fully understood, but i thought it might be the basis of the
tangential space of the point and that the calculated eigenvectors are
in tangent space and not in parameter space but even in tangent space
complex coordinates dont make sense to me. My understanding of
differential geometry might be very wrong, im thankful for evry answer.